# Grouping by 4 Hours Intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to get the average of some data that I have in 4 hours intervals, my app is in Ruby on Rails, so I don't know if I should write a PostgreSQL query or do it in the Model of the application, nor I don't know how I will do it in either.
The simple version of the model is something like this:

```
id    heart_rate    timestamp
```

I also need for 1 hour, and 1 day interval but I already know how to do that, on the SQL side at least:

```
SELECT AVG(heart_rate), to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ts
FROM vital_signs
GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY ts ASC;
```

Comment: 4 hrs, starting where? 00:00? so 00:00, 04:00, 08:00 ?

Comment: @Rogier yeah, 00-04, 04-08, 08-12, 12-04, 04-08, 08-00

Answer (score 1):

24 hrs / 4 = 6 segments.

Convert your date to hours, then do a **integer division** (DIV). That will give you 0-5 numbers. Each remainder representing a segment.

This example is for MySQL (and not Rails), replace the DIV (Integer division function of MySQL) with Postgress equivalent.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(heart_rate), HOUR(timestamp) DIV 4, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    vital_signs
GROUP BY 
    DATE(timestamp), 
    HOUR(timestamp) DIV 4;
```

You can group on the date seperately, so per day you getting the avg. results.

You can execute SQL directly within Rails via:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "<sql>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulating the mathematical remainder is a good option as :

```
Model.count(group: 'CAST((24 - hour(table.created_at))/4 as UNSIGNED)')
```

It will give you a hash with count of each group of four hours as this

```
{0=>2, 1=>1, 3=>1, 6=>2}
```

6 represents start of day 0:00 till 4:00 and so on

You can get the average using the following :

```
Model.average(:field ,group: 'CAST((24 - hour(table.created_at))/4 as UNSIGNED)')
```

Comment: But I need the averages in those timeframes, not how many are there

Comment: Model.average(:heart_rate,group: 'CAST((24 - hour(table.created_at))/4 as UNSIGNED)')

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
MyModel.select("(CASE 
  WHEN hour(created_at) < 4 then '00-04'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 4 and hour(created_at) < 8 then '04-08'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 8 and hour(created_at) < 12 then '08-12'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 12 and hour(created_at) < 16 then '12-16'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 16 and hour(created_at) < 20 then '16-20'
  ELSE '20-24' END) AS delta,
  count(*) as qty").
group("delta")
```

Or simply:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT (CASE 
  WHEN hour(created_at) < 4 then '00-04'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 4 and hour(created_at) < 8 then '04-08'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 8 and hour(created_at) < 12 then '08-12'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 12 and hour(created_at) < 16 then '12-16'
  WHEN hour(created_at) >= 16 and hour(created_at) < 20 then '16-20'
  ELSE '20-24' END) AS delta,
  count(*) as qty
  FROM  my_table
  group by delta;")
```

But the idea is to let your database engine handle the grouping instead of trying to do something like that in ruby code.